# Cache problem in Drupal 6  when updating node

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks, caching, media

When I update a node programmatically the node is updated successfully, but it doesn't display updated content. It only display the previous content.

How can I make the node display the updated content?

Comment: Are you updating the node via code or the ui?

Comment: Since your title and tags indicate there is caching involved, perhaps you should tell us something about your actual cache setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming D6, You have to use the reset flag (third argument) in your [node_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/6).

Answer (score 0):

You can clear cache with the help of below code

```
<?php include_once './includes/bootstrap.inc'; drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL); drupal_flush_all_caches(); ?>
```